# Add indentation on certain items in DropDownList - ASP.net MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've seen a few questions that seem similiar to my issue, but I haven't been able to nail my question yet - so I'm hoping someone has either had the same issue or knows how best to approach this.

I have a ***SelectedItemList*** of Locations from a database. It returns a list of ***Locations***, mostly cities but some countries are listed too. This list would appear as such;

```
Australia
Melbourne
Perth
Sydney
Bermuda
Canada
Calgary
Toronto
Vancouver
```

All the items in the list have an Id and Text property, and any cities that belong to countries have a *ParentLocation_Id* property, which corresponds to the country Id *(Australia is 8, so Sydney and Perth will have "ParentLocation_Id" of 8, etc.)* So I know this is the conditional I will use to target those items within the list, in order to indent the correct ones.

I would like to use the @Html.DropDownListFor() method and be able to target the countries in order to indent them, so the list would appear within the Select list like so;

[image]

but I wondered if there was a neater way to do this by using an HTML Extension. Has anyone ever tried this before?

I have managed it so far by doing it this way, but you can see it looks hideous :(

```
<select id="SelectedLocation" name="SelectedLocation">
                    @{
                        foreach (var location in Model.Locations)
                        {
                            if (location.Item.ParentLocation != null && location.Item.ParentLocation.Id != null)
                            {
                                <option value="@location.Item.Id" class="styled">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@location.Item.Text</option>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <option value="@location.Item.Id" class="styled">@location.Item.Text</option>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </select>
```

It may even be that this is the only way to achieve this UI, but I'd love to know if anyone thinks of anything better to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, you're doing it right when using a plain `Select`.
If you want fancier rendering, it may be time to switch to custom controls.

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to select Australia (as well as its cities)?

Comment: Yep @StephenMuecke, all items on the list are selectable.

Comment: You could write an extension method, but that would be an overkill unless you have multiple uses for an 'indented' dropdownlist. You couls always put that code in a partial (or `EditorTempate`) but your current code is missing he necessary code for correct 2-way binding and for client side validation.

Comment: If I manage to nail the indented dropdownlist, I will use it in quite a lot of places - so in order to reduce the amount of ugly code, I would almost certainly move that into a partial and fix the binding/validation issues. That list is also not exhaustive, so in order to future-proof the readability of that list, I think it's best I do something other than what I've got so far!

Comment: If you do want to go down the extension method path, then start with the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs). But in your case, instead of passing `IEnumerable<SelecListItem>`, it will be `IEnumerable<YourClass>` where `YourClass` contains properties for `Value`, `Text` and `bool IsIndented`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for helping with my issue.

I spoke with my boss re my problem, and he suggested I was over-complicating things slightly by wanting to do an Extension method.

I have managed to get the look and effect I want from a simple radio-button list, a little bit of JS and some styling.

It's taken me a little bit longer but I've learned something so I'm seeing it as a worthwhile task :)

Anyone whom is interested can check out the code below

```js
       /* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    $('#selectLocation').click(function () {
        document.getElementById("locationDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        return false;
    });

    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    };
    $('input[name="SelectedLocation"]').on('change', function () {
        var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#selectLocation").text($("label[for='" + idVal + "']").text());
    });
```

```css
.field {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 1em 0;
    width: 100%;
}

field-label {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    width: 180px;
    line-height: 140%;
    font-size: .9375em;
}
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
#selectLocation a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #333;
}
#selectLocation {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #fff url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: right 10px center;
    background-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
#locationDropdown {
    border: 1px solid #799BD2;
    height: 300px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul#locationDropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}
#content ul {
    list-style: disc outside;
}
.dropdown-content {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.lblLocation {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
input[name="SelectedLocation"] {
    display: none;
}
.indent {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.indentExtra {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.dropdown-content.show {
    margin: 0;
    width: 110%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="selectLocation">
    <span>Select location</span>
  </a>
  <ul id="locationDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="8" value="Australia">
                                        <input id="8" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="8">
                                        <span class="indent">Australia</span>
                                    </label>


    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="9" value="Melbourne">
                                        <input id="9" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="9">
                                        <span class="indentExtra">Melbourne</span>
                                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="10" value="Perth">
                                        <input id="10" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="10">
                                        <span class="indentExtra">Perth</span>
                                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="11" value="Sydney">
                                        <input id="11" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="11">
                                        <span class="indentExtra">Sydney</span>
                                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="12" value="Bermuda">
                                        <input id="12" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="12">
                                        <span class="indent">Bermuda</span>
                                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="13" value="Canada">
                                        <input id="13" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="13">
                                        <span class="indent">Canada</span>
                                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="14" value="Calgary">
                                        <input id="14" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="14">
                                        <span class="indentExtra">Calgary</span>
                                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="15" value="Toronto">
                                        <input id="15" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="15">
                                        <span class="indentExtra">Toronto</span>
                                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="lblLocation" for="16" value="Vancouver">
                                        <input id="16" name="SelectedLocation" type="radio" value="16">
                                        <span class="indentExtra">Vancouver</span>
                                    </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks again to all who commented!